# PHP Search and remove numeric array value

Tags: php

I have a php array with strings and I'd like to delete the keys that have a string containing only numbers.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val)
    if (is_numeric($key)) // only numbers, a point and an `e` like in 1.1e10
        unset($array[$key]);
```

This unsets all the entries where there are only numbers.

Comment: That's basically CooPer answer with typo corrected. Give him some time to fix it instead of duplicating the answer - it was his idea.

Comment: Isn't he looking for numeric keys, not values?

Comment: @JanTuroň see the time... My answer is older than his?

Comment: @JanTuroň we post at same time

Comment: @bwoebi: eh, his answer appeared sooner in my browser. However, it were just couple of seconds, therefore I take back the -1 from me. Sorry.

Comment: @middaparka we use unset($array($key)) **NOT** unset($value)

Comment: Stop fighting. Bwoebi posted first and I saw it.

Comment: I changed your code a little, ``is_numeric`` wouldn't work for sure, that's why I changed it to ``ctype_digit`` and now it works perfectly.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

Filtering the array would be the most elegant way:

```
$array = array_filter($array, 'is_numeric');
```

This returns an array with only those values for whom `is_numeric()` is true.

Comment: Yes indeed, it looks way more elegant than the answers below, but I'm searching for numeric-only strings.

Comment: If you need only digits, without any other symbols that may appear in a numeric string, you can filter with `is_int`.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
  if(is_numeric($value))
      unset($array($key));
```